# Is Template 10 available for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, c#, templates, uwp

Visual Studio Template 10 Template Pack is a rich library of helpers, services, and base classes for new and existing Windows UWP apps to maximize awesomeness and minimize boilerplate garbage. I cannot find anything on starting a new Visual Studio  2019 project using Template 10.

Is it available? If yes, what is the procedure please? If no, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Template 10 is [only supported by Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerry-nixon.Template10TemplatePack), not by Visual Studio 2019. There is an unanswered [Visual Studio 2019 support #1686](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/1686) issue  on GitHub asking if there is some plan to give Template 10 support to Visual Studio 2019. I don't know of any workarounds that would make it possible to graft the unsupported Template 10 Template Pack onto Visual Studio 2019.